# UPDATE, DELETE in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

can anybody show me how to perform UPDATE, DELETE sql command in c# with sql compact edition 4.0?? i have found this code in another post.can i perform UPDATE/DELETE here?? plz help..

```
string strConn = Properties.Settings.Default.SqlConnectionString;
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into CustTable(ID, Name) values (@Val1, @val2)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", customer.ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val2", customer.Name);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have given an example but I would really recommend you to read some good book before working on any project

**update command**

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
{
con.Open();
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("update CustTable set col1 = @Val1", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", customer.ID);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

**Delete Command**

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(strConn))
{
con.Open();
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("DELETE from CustTable where col1 = @Val1", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", customer.ID);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```